# XSLT parsing failed

Tags: xml, xslt

Everything matches up with my xml file and the only thing that's diffrent is that I have multiple descriptors of Genres, Dice, and Theme. I know that growth is kept lowercase. I'm using Ubuntu and I know only how to test with the firefox browser, so all I've been getting is "Error Loading Stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed." Any help is appreciated.

```
    <?xml version ="1.0"?>

    <xsl-stylesheet version = "1.0"
        xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method = "html" omit-xml-declaration = "no"
            doctype-system = 
                    "http://www.w3c.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
            doctype-public = "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"/>
        <xsl: template match = "/"> 

    <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title> Tabletop RPG systems </title>
         </head>
    <body>
    <table border = "1" bgcolor = "wheat">
        <thread>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Focus</th>
                <th>IP</th>
                <th>Genres</th>
                <th>Dice</th>
                <th>growth</th>
                <th>Theme</th>
            </tr>
        </thread>

        <xsl:for-each select = "/tRPG/Name">

        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "Company"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "Focus"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "IP"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "Genres"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "Dice"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "growth"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "Theme"/></td>

        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        </body>
     </html>

        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of syntactical errors at the XML level:

1. Change

   ```
   <xsl-stylesheet version = "1.0"
   ```

   to

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   <xsl: template match = "/">
   ```

   to

   ```
   <xsl:template match = "/">
   ```

Then your XSLT will at least be a well-formed XML document as it must minimally be.